# JUnit Test cases Using Mockito: null pointer exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I am writing a `JUnit` test cases using `Mockito`. I have populated a list using reflection with mock objects of IIOImage class of java. Though my list has objects, my test case is failing and I am getting a null pointer exception. Can anyone help?

```
_sourceList=(List) Whitebox.getInternalState(OneClass, "_sourceListContent");

_sourceList.add(Mockito.mock(IIOImage.class)); 
_sourceList.add(Mockito.mock(IIOImage.class));
Field listfield=OneClass.class.getDeclaredField("_sourceListContent");
listfield.setAccessible(true);
listfield.set(oneclass, _sourceImages);
System.out.println(_sourceList.size()+"is size");

for(int i=0;i<=_sourceImages.size(); i++) //this loop is giving null
{   
      IIOImage img = (IIOImage)_sourceImages.get(i);
      SomeClass data=Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
      data=(SomeClass)img.getMetadata();
      data.dumpData();
}
```

It returns the size here, but causes problem when I run the test case saying null pointer.

here's the stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at SomeClass.SomeClassTest.dumpRequestTest(IPRequestTest.java:285)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: I have added the stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating instances as mocks:

```
_sourceList.add(Mockito.mock(IIOImage.class));
```

Later on you retireive them one by one and call this method on each:

```
IIOImage img = (IIOImage)_sourceImages.get(i);
data=(SomeClass)img.getMetadata();
```

You have not declared what Mockito should return when this method is called (using the when(..).thenReturn(..) syntax), thus Mockito returns a default null value.

When you then call the:

```
data.dumpData();
```

You get a `NullPointerException` as `data` is `null`.

**Fix**

- Declare what should be return by `when(img.getMetadata()).thenReturn(..)`.
- Use Mockito.spy instead of mock.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion, but Mockito.spy is not working for me and throwing a new set of exceptions. img.getMetadata() is returning null when I call It. Is it because of this I am facing problem?

Comment: You have to declare the returned value then..when(img.getMetadata()).thenReturn(/*  some instance */)

Comment: It's not working out. because of that null value returned by data.dumpData() My test case is failing and returning NullPointerException.

Comment: Whats inside data.dumpData();? I dont see you assigning the return value of this method to any variable. Maybe post the whole test so we dont miss anything..

Comment: public void dumpData()
   {
    NodeList childNodes = _root.getChildNodes();
    for(int i=0;i<childNodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
      Element elem = (Element) childNodes.item(i);
      String node = elem.getNodeName();
    }
  }

Comment: I need to check the size of the list using assertEquals, whether it has the correct number of objects I have added. in the above snippet the code within the for loop is causing the execution to break and giving null

Comment: If dumpData() is a public method.. then i would validate its logic in a separate test. Do not try to do too much in your unit tests.. they should be testing one single logical case of a single public method. You mock everything else. Again.. mock that metadata object.. when(img.getMetadata()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(Metadata.class))

Comment: Great. Glad i could help